# Get a list of Com Objects in ASP

Tags: com, command-line

a task at my hand requires me to move an ASP application from one server to another. For this, I need two command line tool like stuff to know the following info.

1. Get the list of com objects used in this asp project.
2. Get the list of registered com objects in my existing server.

Any Idea ?

Comment: What would a list of 100.000 COM objects registered on your server be good for when you actually only need to know a few of them?

Comment: True, 100's of COM objects are really not useful for me per se.
But, I would at least have a list that I can use to know If a COM object at hand is  already registered.

Comment: Just register it again. You won't do any harm when it was registered already.

Comment: Knowing if it is registered is only half the issue anyway. It could easily be registered but the DLL could have been deleted or moved since. As svinto says elsewhere, the only way to be sure a component is registered and working it to create an object (preferably using the same user account as ASP).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, Script pointed by Rory and approach suggested by andynormancx were helpful. I was able to get it working on my new server. You guys rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search for "CreateObject" should some up all the COM objects created from VBScript in the ASP pages. You should also check the global.asa for any object tags, which is the other way COM objects get instantiated. If you also have server side Javascript then you should also look for "ActiveXObject".

I expect you could extract this info with commandline tools like grep etc, but unless you are doing this over and over again on different setups then it would almost certainly be quicker to do in VS.NET or something like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
How Do I detect If a COM component is already Registered. Or Get a list of COM components registered on the server.

Comment: You can try to create the object and see if that works or not to see if it's registered.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @andynormancx, search your code for appropriate calls:

- CreateObject
- GetObject
- object tags in global.asa
- ActiveXObject (from javascript)

You can use WMI objects to get a list of all COM objects on the existing server. This probably won't be hugely useful, but maybe do this on your new server and then do a diff between the two to identify differences that might be important. A sample script for getting the list of objects is [here](http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/COM/321.aspx):